# turn the whole array content in the array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to turn the array content after converting the string to bit String to set the 0bit, 1bit, 2bit, 3bit in the java object at the right position.
13 --> 1101 --> 1011 (aim)
Currently before turning the values:

```
secondByteBitArray[0] = "1"
secondByteBitArray[1] = "1"
```

After turning the values:

```
secondByteBitArray[0] = "1"
secondByteBitArray[1] = "0"
```

**code**

```
    String secondByte = "13";
    String secondByteBits = new BigInteger(secondByte, 16).toString(2);
    String[] secondByteBitArray = secondByteBits.split("(?<=\\G.{1})");     
    for(int i=0; i<secondByteBitArray.length; i++){


    }
```

Is there any java method to do that?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String secondByte = "13";
String secondByteBits = new BigInteger(secondByte, 16).toString(2);
String[] secondByteBitArray = secondByteBits.split("(?<=\\G.{1})");     
for(int i=0; i<secondByteBitArray.length/2; i++){ // note the division
    int i2 = secondByteBitArray.length-i-1;
    // swap
    String aux = secondByteBitArray[i];
    secondByteBitArray[i] = secondByteBitArray[i2];
    secondByteBitArray[i2] = aux;
}
```